# Trying to install Purelayout using cocoa pods in swift project

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks, cocoapods, pure-layout

I am currently having problems installing Pure Layout using Cocoa Pods. Ive managed to install it fine in a blank project with no problems. But when installing into my project i keep getting the following error:

ld: framework not found PureLayout
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Ive had a search through stack overflow for any possible solutions and have tried adding the framework search path to the target, trying to delete cocoa pods and do a fresh install onto the project.

Initially before adding 'PureLayout' to the pod file i got a similar error:

ld: framework not found Pods

To resolve this i removed the red pod framework file from the linked library and framework folder. Which then built fine.

Thank you in advance for anyone who helps me solve this.

Below is my Podfile:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '8.1'
# Uncomment this line if you're using Swift
use_frameworks!

target '****' do

pod 'Google/Analytics'
pod 'Fabric'
pod 'Crashlytics'
pod 'PureLayout'

end

target '****Tests' do

end
```

Answer (score 1):

Managed to solve this issue by:

-Select Pods Project
-Build Settings
-Set BaseSDK to iOS SDK (since pod install clears it)
-Set Build Valid Architecture Only to NO.

Following this process the project now builds. I was able to import Pure Layout into my Bridging Header and access the pure layout functions in any of my view controller classes.